# Collapsing a special kind of list structure

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I have a following kind of list in R:

```
List of 4
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] -3.68 -1.5 1.71 1.75 -0.67
  ..$ lower   : num -2.92
  ..$ midpoint: num 1
  ..$ upper   : num 4.92
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 0.15395 0.00512 0.02635 0.0388 0.17721
  ..$ lower   : num 0.00422
  ..$ midpoint: num 0.167
  ..$ upper   : num 0.615
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5, 1:3] 0.841 0.514 1.443 1.096 0.913 ...
  ..$ lower   : num [1:3] -0.96 0.04 1.04
  ..$ midpoint: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ upper   : num [1:3] 2.96 3.96 4.96
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 6.78 -0.28 2.565 0.553 14.275
  ..$ lower   : num -4.84
  ..$ midpoint: num 3
  ..$ upper   : num 10.8
```

The first, the second and the fourth item in the upper level list are as they should, but the third item should be collapsed into three separate items. So the end result should be look something like this:

```
List of 4
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] -3.68 -1.5 1.71 1.75 -0.67
  ..$ lower   : num -2.92
  ..$ midpoint: num 1
  ..$ upper   : num 4.92
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 0.15395 0.00512 0.02635 0.0388 0.17721
  ..$ lower   : num 0.00422
  ..$ midpoint: num 0.167
  ..$ upper   : num 0.615
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 1 2 3 ... #This should be the FIRST column in the prices matrix of the third item in the original list, 1 2 3 just for the illustration purposes
  ..$ lower   : num -0.96
  ..$ midpoint: num 1
  ..$ upper   : num 2.96
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 1 2 3 ... #This should be the SECOND column in the prices matrix of the third item in the original list, 1 2 3 ... just for the illustration purposes
  ..$ lower   : num -0.04
  ..$ midpoint: num 2
  ..$ upper   : num 3.96
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 1 2 3 ... #This should be the THIRD column in the prices matrix of the third item in the original list, 1 2 3 ... just for the illustration purposes
  ..$ lower   : num 1.04
  ..$ midpoint: num 3
  ..$ upper   : num 4.96
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 6.78 -0.28 2.565 0.553 14.275
  ..$ lower   : num -4.84
  ..$ midpoint: num 3
  ..$ upper   : num 10.8
```

Is there a better way than just start filling a new list in a for loop, so that:

```
newlist <- list()
newlist_i <- 1 #This index increases faster than i, whenever we encounter a "compressed" list item.
for(i in 1:length(origlist)) {
    if(!is.null(dim(origlist[[i]]$prices)) { #dim(vector) returns NULL
        for(j in 1:ncol(prices)) {
            newlist[[newlist_i+j-1]]$prices <- origlist[[i]]$prices[,j]
            newlist[[newlist_i+j-1]]$lower <- origlist[[i]]$lower[j]
            newlist[[newlist_i+j-1]]$midpoint <- origlist[[i]]$midpoint[j]
            newlist[[newlist_i+j-1]]$upper <- origlist[[i]]$upper[j]
        }
        newlist_i = newlist_i + dim(origlist[[i]]$prices) - 1
    } else {
        newlist[[i]] <- origlist[[i]]
        newlist_i = newlist_i + 1
    }
}
```

But the for loop looks so ugly and complicated. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please include the output from `dput(origlist)` to your question.

Comment: @margusl , this is a valid point, and my mistake, sorry about that. This would have been an essential part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ModifyList` + `asplit` + `lapply` Using data from [`@asd-tm`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77268062/revisions) (Give credits where due)

```
origlist <- md
```

---

```
lapply(origlist, \(x)
  if(length(dim(x$prices))) 
    do.call(Map, c(list,modifyList(x, list(prices = asplit(x$prices,2)))))
  else list(x)
)|>unlist(FALSE)

List of 6
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 1.097 0.435 -0.326 1.149 0.994
  ..$ lower   : num 0.548
  ..$ midpoint: num 0.239
  ..$ upper   : num -0.628
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 1.361 -0.6 2.187 1.533 -0.236
  ..$ lower   : num -1.03
  ..$ midpoint: num -0.71
  ..$ upper   : num 0.257
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5(1d)] -0.247 -0.348 -0.952 -0.045 -0.785
  ..$ lower   : num -0.641
  ..$ midpoint: num 0.118
  ..$ upper   : num -0.256
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5(1d)] -1.668 -0.38 0.919 -0.575 0.608
  ..$ lower   : num -0.85
  ..$ midpoint: num -0.947
  ..$ upper   : num 1.84
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5(1d)] -1.6179 -0.0556 0.5194 0.3012 0.1057
  ..$ lower   : num -1.02
  ..$ midpoint: num -0.491
  ..$ upper   : num -0.652
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ prices  : num [1:5] 0.2354 0.078 -0.9619 -0.0713 1.4446
  ..$ lower   : num 0.452
  ..$ midpoint: num 0.0412
  ..$ upper   : num -0.422
```

Answer (score 1):

I would offer the following base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(my_d, \(x){
          rbind(x$prices |> matrix(5), x$lower, x$midpoint, x$upper) |> t()
        }) 
) |> apply(MARGIN = 1, \(x) {
  list(
  prices = x[1:5],
  lower = x[6],
  midpoint = x[7],
  upper = x[8]
  )
})
```

Or if length of `prices` is unknown:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(my_d, \(x){
          cbind(x$prices |> matrix(length(x$lower), byrow = T), x$lower, x$midpoint, x$upper) 
        }) 
) |> apply(MARGIN = 1, \(x) {
  list(
    prices = x[1:(length(x) - 3)],
    lower = x[length(x) - 2],
    midpoint = x[length(x) - 1],
    upper = x[length(x)]
  )
})
```

Both scripts return the same output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$prices
[1]  1.9196255  0.1770681  2.3306149 -0.8893725  0.7117880

[[1]]$lower
[1] 1.317551

[[1]]$midpoint
[1] 0.4215168

[[1]]$upper
[1] -0.8721538


[[2]]
[[2]]$prices
[1] -1.0674630  0.2179483 -2.2493795  0.2747926 -1.3451170

[[2]]$lower
[1] 1.444299

[[2]]$midpoint
[1] 1.212617

[[2]]$upper
[1] 0.1006223


[[3]]
[[3]]$prices
[1] -0.3124539  0.8772849  0.4090815  0.4909305 -0.9445474

[[3]]$lower
[1] -1.182347

[[3]]$midpoint
[1] -1.285585

[[3]]$upper
[1] -1.537147


[[4]]
[[4]]$prices
[1] -0.6609199  0.2626416 -0.2137965 -0.2261824 -0.8723562

[[4]]$lower
[1] -1.693114

[[4]]$midpoint
[1] -1.607736

[[4]]$upper
[1] -0.05325191


[[5]]
[[5]]$prices
[1] -0.8811282 -0.8030718  2.4720077 -0.1622402  0.9657835

[[5]]$lower
[1] -0.4743322

[[5]]$midpoint
[1] -0.9583107

[[5]]$upper
[1] 0.264364


[[6]]
[[6]]$prices
[1] -0.1863864  0.2615337 -0.3725853 -0.1614547  0.4465152

[[6]]$lower
[1] 0.03844349

[[6]]$midpoint
[1] -0.5716921

[[6]]$upper
[1] -1.85495
```

Used data:

```
my_d <- list(
  list(prices = rnorm(5),
       lower = rnorm(1),
       midpoint = rnorm(1),
       upper = rnorm(1)),
  list(prices = rnorm(5),
       lower = rnorm(1),
       midpoint = rnorm(1),
       upper = rnorm(1)),
  list(prices = matrix(rnorm(5*3), 5),
       lower = rnorm(3),
       midpoint = rnorm(3),
       upper = rnorm(3)),
  list(prices = rnorm(5),
       lower = rnorm(1),
       midpoint = rnorm(1),
       upper = rnorm(1))
)
```